# How to download files from password protected folder in Sharepoint via HTTP c#

Tags: c#, http, http-headers, httpwebrequest, webclient

I have a sharepoint link to a password protected folder. The link is in the form of **"https://www.xxx.sharepoint.com/:f/s/some-other-stuff"** and I have the password for this. Once I go to this link in the browser and enter the folder password, I am redirected to another link in the form of **"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/random-stuff/Forms/more-random-stuff"**. I can download the files I need from here.

I want to do this in c# either using HTTP libraries or Sharepoint API if possible. I've tried a few things with HTTPWebRequest and POST etc. but I'm unable to get it working correclty. Any help resolving this issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please share with us your coding attempts to solve the issue.

Comment: Are we talking about Basic authentication? If so then you can use the following pattern to bypass the login: `http://{username}:{password}@my.server.com/resource` ([More details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#URL_encoding))